# Circles tangent to a parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

For the past two weeks I was struggling with solving the following problem.

Description of variables:

$(x_n,y_n)$ - center point of the circle $C_n$

$r_n$ - radius of the circle $C_n$

Given the curve $k:y=x^2,x\geqslant0$, and knowing that for every $n\in\mathbb{N} \wedge  n>0$ $C_n$ is tangent to $k$, the $OX$ axis and externally tangent to $C_{n-1}$, find the explicit formula for $x_n$, $y_n$ and $r_n$ given the initial condition $C_0: (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r_0^2$, where $C_0$ is tangent to $OX$ and $k$.

It is obvious that $r_n=y_n$, but I did not manage to derive a sensible system of equations.
I said "sensible", because this is the only one I could think of:

$\begin{cases} \frac{x_T-x_n}{y_n-y_T}=2x_T \\ y_T=x_T^2\\\sqrt{(x_T-x_n)^2+(y_T-y_n)^2}=y_n \\ \sqrt{(x_n-x_{n-1})^2+(y_n-y_{n-1})^2}=y_n+y_{n-1} \end{cases}$

Is there no more convenient way to approach this?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: I tried this, got the same equations as you, and got stuck. I think maybe family of circles is a better approach?

Nice question btw.

Comment: I parametrised the parameters $x_n$ and $y_n$ in terms of $t_n$ and then tried to use the last equation in an attempt to relate $t_n$ and $t_{n-1}$. But the algebra involved is too complex, even maple got stuck.

Comment: I was using Mathematica trying to solve this system and slightly different versions of it, but in the second substition the roots are already really complex.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be an answer as such but more of a suggestion as to how one might be able to proceed further.

It seems that the equation satisfied by the coordinates of the centre $(x,y)$ of any circle which touches the parabola and the $x$ axis is itself very complicated: $$x^2=\left(\frac{8y-1+\sqrt{16y+1}}{8}\right)\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{16y+1}}{4}\right)^2$$

Despite its appearance this is a fairly innocent-looking curve passing as you would expect between the parabola $y=x^2$ and the $x$ axis.

This was obtained by just considering the requirement that each circle must touch the parabola and the $x$ axis. Therefore somehow this would need to be coupled with the requirement that the circles touch each other in series, which can be written as $$x_{n+1}=x_n+2\sqrt{y_ny_{n+1}}$$
But I don't know how to link these up. Any ideas?

Comment: If I would have written an answer, it won't have looked much different from this one.

Answer (score -1):

Standard  parametric equn of parabola $ y = x^2 / (4 f) $ is

( in this case we can take $ f= \frac14 $ )

$$ x = 2 f t ; \, y = f t^2; \, t = \tan \phi $$

Radius of contacting circle $ = y  \sec\phi   = f t^2 \sqrt{1+t^2} $

Distance to right of parabola point x-coordinate is $ y\,  t = f t^3  $

So the center of circle on x-axis $ ( 2 f t + f t^3, 0) $

Rest you can proceed.

EDIT1:

Contacting circles as shown.

$r$ is radius of bigger contact circle given *independently* as in sketch.

$$ x = 2 ft + r \sin \phi = 2 f t  + \frac {r  t}{ \sqrt{1+t^2}}$$

$$ y = ft^2 - \frac{r}{ \sqrt{1+t^2} }   $$

So you can solve for  $ t =  \tan \phi $ when $ y=r $ from the resulting sixth degree transcendental equation :

$$  \frac{f\; t^2}{r}= 1 -\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+t^2} } $$

[image: TgtCircles]

Comment: It is stated in the problem that the circles are tangent to the x-axis, not that  their centers lie on the x-axis.
Or maybe I am missing something in your solution

Comment: That is why it is only  a *HINT* . In a full answer the contacting circle is modified to push it up to be tangent to the x-axis,

Comment: Ok, so what is $ϕ$ in your hint?

Comment: Slope of tangent shown in edit. Differential equation can be found though.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't quite understand your approach. You use $ϕ$ for parametrization, but we cannot know its value without determining the point of tangency with the parabola.

Comment: In solution of equations you generally *pretend* that it is a temporarily unknown variable to be solved later, bring in other constraints and defining relationships and then solve to remove the pretension. The above can be solved in Mathematica to obtain real roots.